# Error: In html dump files after web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, httprequest

I'm trying to dump html pages after web scraping using java.

```
Matcher linkState= BaseAgent.getMatches(browser, linkReg, null);
if (linkState.find()) {
    this.navigate(browser, fieldValuesSet,LOGIN, "http://isupplier.dpispecialtyfoods.com"+getMatcherGroupData(linkState,1));
    //this.dumpDocument(browser,null,"login.html","C:\\Users\\vassudha.singh\\HighRadiusCorporation");
    this.dumpDocument(browser,"login.html");
} else {
    LOG.debug(" Link mismatch or not found");
}
```

But the login page shows error.. the .js file contains the error: "var _UixWindowOpenError='A popup window blocker has been detected in your browser.Popup blockers interfere with the operation of this application. Please disable your popup blocker or allow popups from this site."

I have disabled the popup blocker in internet explorer and Chrome and Firefox using

Tools > Pop-up Blocker > Turn off popup blocker
Ads > allow ads pop-up

But the error still occurs. How can I check for and disable the popup blocker? Or is there something I cant detect.

```
http-outgoing-3 << "<!-- METADATA_SOURCE - JRAD --><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html dir="ltr" lang="en-US-ORACLE9I"><head><title>Error</title><meta name="generator" content="Oracle UIX"><link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" type="text/css" href="/OA_HTML/cabo/styles/cache/swanEXTN-custom-2_3_6_9-en.css"><script>var _UixWindowOpenError='A popup window blocker has been detected in your browser. Popup blockers interfere with the operation of this application. Please disable your popup blocker or allow popups from this site.';</script><script src="/OA_HTML/cabo/jsLibs/Common2_3_6_9.js"></script><script>_defaultTZ()</script><script language="javascript" src="/OA_HTML/cabo/oajsLibs/oafcoreR12RUP6.js"></script></head><body class="xk" onload="_checkLoad(event)" onunload="_checkUnload(event)"><iframe id="_pprIFrame" name="_pprIFrame" frameborder="0" longdesc="#" title="" src="about:blank" style="position:absolute;top:-100;visibility:hidden" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
```

I have also checked all the headers and all the regex for scraping.
The login html page looks like this:

[login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je558.png)

If you need logfiles or code. I'm happy to share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Web pages usually load external resources like js and json. If the content is loaded through such a resource, a dumped html file will no longer be able to access that content because of CORS.